# List Adapter first and last id conflict

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-adapter

I had a list of arrays and passed it thru adapter to fill my List.

**Actually, I wanted to set some color for the clicked item.**

**The problem is, Whenever I click the first item, both first and last item gets same background color.**

*Code: Test.java*

```
//To keep track of previously clicked textview
TextView last_clicked=null;
ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_activity_list);

//My test array
String[] data={"one","two","three","four","five","six"};

list=new ArrayList<String>(data.length);
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));

//evolist is my custom layout
adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(c,R.layout.evolist,list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter); 
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> ad, View v, int pos, long id){

                        //set black for other
                        if(last_clicked!=null)
                            last_clicked.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                        //set red color for selected item
                        TextView tv=(TextView)v;
         //I also tried TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvo)
         //I tried printing tv.getId() and noticed that both first and last had same IDs
                        tv.setBackgroundColor( Color.RED );
                        last_clicked=tv;

    }
  });
```

*Layout: evolist.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp">
</TextView>
```

Where am I wrong, or only I get this sort of error?
(Samsung galaxy y duos; 2.3.7)

Comment: I don't know why its happening, but if its just due to ids, try to give ids externally using tv.setId() method. That might work

Comment: @shreya shah: Can u try this snippet and comment?

Answer (score 1):

What I think is happening is because the `views` are recycled in `ListView` (when you scroll up, the `View` that disappears from the top is the one that is used for the item that appears at the bottom, referred to as `convertView`).

Try overriding `getView()` and set the color of `convertView` to Black.

**Edit:**

Define a class member:

```
String selected_item="";
```

Then set it to the value of the selected item:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> ad, View v, int pos, long id){
       selected_item=((TextView) v).getText().toString();
       (TextView)v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
  });
```

And for `getView()`

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
            if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                 LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView=li.inflate(R.layout.evolist, null);
               }
            if(((TextView) convertView).getText().toString().equals(selected_item)) ((TextView)convertView).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            else ((TextView)convertView).setBackgroundColor(Color.Black);
            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: You need to **override** `ArrayAdapter.getView()`

Comment: This method is abstract (not implemented in ArrayAdapter) so you cannot call it, but if you override it, the system will use it when filling the View of the new Item with data. I will show you sample code

Comment: Ofcourse,I wrote a separate class extending BaseAdapter, defined getCount,getItem,and getView() in which, I set bgcolor for textview as black and added onclicklistener in which i set bgcolor of clicked view as red and last_click as clicked view .. anyway the same thing ..  both last and first items get same color

Comment: add `((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvo)).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);` before returning convertView

Answer (score 0):

Please update your code.

You are going to set the findViewById but there you have set the layout.

Check this line:

```
ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.layout.my_activity);
```

Comment me after updating your code.